# Windows CMD command to run a command inside every subdirectory?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, recursive

I have a batch script I wrote called "joiner.bat." It needs to run inside each of 730 sub-directories of a folder. The joiner.bat file has already been copied into each of the sub-folders, it just needs to run in each. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

`for %f in (*) do joiner.bat %f`

I tried that command outside of a batch file just on the command prompt but it did nothing. I need the command to go into a folder, run the command, go back to the previous folder, into the next, run the command, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    cd %%a 
    call joiner.bat
)
```

create this as a batch file in the top directory.

I modified your bach file from the comments.  You may need more parens and DelayedExpansion requires the use of ! instead of %.  Try this

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%a in (*) do ( 
    cd %%a 
    copy /b *.xml newfile.xml 
    @echo off 
    SET "CDIR=%~dp0" 
    SET "CDIR=!CDIR:~0,-1!" 
    FOR %%i IN ("!CDIR!") DO (
        SET "PARENTFOLDERNAME=%%~nxi" 
        move newfile.xml "C:\users\lacroixja01\desktop\test\%PARENTFOLDERNAME%.xml" 
        )
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. After that command failed, I decided to copy your code and joiner.bat into one and to see if that would help and it didn't. This is the entire bat file: 

`for /d %%a in (*) do (
 cd %%a
 copy /b *.xml newfile.xml

 @echo off
 SET "CDIR=%~dp0"
 SET "CDIR=%CDIR:~0,-1%"
 FOR %%i IN ("%CDIR%") DO SET "PARENTFOLDERNAME=%%~nxi"

 move newfile.xml "C:\users\lacroixja01\desktop\test\%PARENTFOLDERNAME%.xml"
)`

Comment: Windows batch doesn't deal well with modifying variable in a loop. Try adding  this to the top of the batch file: setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Comment: I posted modified code to my answer.  its not tested!

Comment: This did it:

`for /d %%a in (*) do (
 pushd %%a

 call joiner.bat

 popd
)`

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify it to look like this:

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    cd %%a 
    call joiner.bat
    cd ..
)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why this works.